# Is this program of binary searching correct?

Tags: c, binary-search

This is the algorithm I wrote in C:

```
int binfin(int vec[],int svec, int tfind) {
    int left=0,right=svec-1,mid,sol=-1;
    do {
        mid=(left+right)>>1;
        if(vec[mid]<tfind) {
            left=mid+1;
        } else if(vec[mid]>tfind) {
            right=mid-1;
        }
    } while(vec[mid]!=tfind && left<=right);

    if(left<=right)
        sol=mid;
    return sol;

}
```

This is part of my homework but the online judge decided its incorrect.

This is just a fragment of the program, although I believe it's the trouble-making part. If its correct, then please tell me.

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?

Comment: ", though i believe its the trouble-making part" -- we need more. This fragment isn't enough to reproduce a problem that we don't even know exists.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've never used a binary search yet where `right` can end up `< left`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, in case right==left is true, and vec[right]>tfind, then right=(left+right)/2-1, where it reduces to right=left-1

Comment: @nicomp Well, as far as I have tested, the main works perfect if it'd gave the position i need to find. so i can conclude that the problem is related to this binary search i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when `svec` in your inputs in 0? That is when then array to find in is empty?

You will calculate `right` to be `-1` and `mid` will also be `-1`. You will then read `vec[-1]` which could invoke undefined behavior.

Also you won't get the correct result.